# Slow response time with complex microsoft word 365 and windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

A software genealogy product produces a very complex .rtf file that I need to edit for publishing in a pdf format. I first save as word docx.   Current file is about 700 pages, others will be over 1,000 before I split into 2.   It has literally thousands of embedded fields for indexing by name, location, footnotes.  I need to use a custom style sheet, do formatting (different sections with odd/even/firstpage reference to header, etc, etc.  ) I used to use windows 7 and and older version of word and it was slow but still worked.

I have windows 10 and office 365. Have turned off autosave, Dropbox synch, OneDrive, autocorrect and use draft mode most of the time.  Documents save only to hard drive.  Task manager does not show maxed out cpu, network, or disk usage, but does show high power usage.

Editing is basically impossible. Literally up to 10 minutes of "not responding" between search and replace, paging down if not in draft mode.

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft 365 and Office 365 [are cloud-based services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-service-descriptions-technet-library)..." Perhaps a limited internet connection slows editing.

1. Try another, *locally installed* (not cloud-based) application, such as free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) *Writer*, which can handle **many** document types, such as DOCX, RTF and even older MS Word DOC files that current versions of Word no longer support. Documents can be converted to PDF using Windows *Print to PDF* driver, or using the *much* more powerful *Writer* menu option *File > Export As > Export as PDF...*, shown below.

[image: Writer Print as PDF Dialog]

2. Try to obtain an *older* version of MS *Word*, as an installed application rather than as a cloud-based service. Of course, there might be security and other issues in using an older application, no longer maintained.
3. *Some* preliminary editing of the RTF file might be accomplished in *Wordpad*. Most versions of MS Windows have WordPad already installed ([until Microsoft removes it](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-is-killing-wordpad-in-windows-after-28-years/), soon), which is designed to deal *locally* with RTF documents. To start it, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *wordp* and select *Wordpad*.

Comment: The desktop apps in Microsoft 365 are not cloud based.

Answer (score 0):

### Converted files always have added complexity compared to native Word files.

.rtf is not a native Word format even though Word can edit such files.

The thing is, your file is likely completely formatted using direct formatting rather than style-based formatting which places a huge burden on Word and dramatically slows it down in large documents. See my page [The Importance of Styles in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm) for examples and links demonstrating this.

You are also likely to have numerous Section breaks that would not be needed and much of the text in Text Boxes rather than in [Frames](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage) or [Tables](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm). Textboxes are graphical elements in Word not in the text layer.

If you have a final .rtf file and are not going to have to repeat the process, you can add styles to your document and apply them every time formatting changes, look for unneeded Section breaks (search for ^b), and look for text boxes that could be eliminated. This is a big project but should vastly speed up the editing once done.

Otherwise, editing in Draft view is going to be your best option.

*I assume from your post that you are editing files on your hard drive using the desktop Word application.*

You can install and run Word 2010, or even Word 2003 in Windows 10 if you have the installation media and product keys.

Disclosure: All hyperlinks are to pages on my website.

Comment: That does not answer the OP's question: why editing was a bit slow in earlier versions of MS Word, and now *abysmally lethargic* in Office365.

Comment: Yes, word on pc.  Agree re: styles and that is what I will do if I can get adequate response from word. Have been using word since it first came out, in initial  DOS version waaaay back when :-)  Tried LibreWrite with the rtf and the docx and it failed to load with an error.   Will now try my older pc with less power and memory but word 10.  And even older thinkpad with windows 7 and word 7 (no longer connect to internet as not longer supported.).  Need some section breaks for different chapters (for headers and footers, start on even etc), and for indexes to change to 3 columns of text.

Comment: I added a note at the end of my answer. You can use Word 2010, 2007, or even 2003 in Windows 10 or 11. You would need the installation media and product key to install. These are all out of product support from Microsoft and never were downloadable products. They can be installed and used on the same computer that has 365.

Comment: Getting a little closer to being able to work.  Draft mode, froze the field updating for indexes (may remove formulas until much later in the editing), no spelling, grammar, autocorrect, no onedrive or dropbox synch, no autosave, save to hard drive for doc and special style template,  no word count or pagination in status bar, etc etc. stripping it down of all its "helpful" bells and whistles.   Will see how it goes. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I am now working on a 1,200 page document with thousands of footnotes, 2 indexes each with thousands of entries. As noted in my question: I have windows 10 and office 365. Have turned off autosave, Dropbox synch, OneDrive, autocorrect and use draft mode most of the time. Documents save only to hard drive. Task manager does not show maxed out cpu, network, or disk usage, but does show high power usage.
**My PC updated to windows 11 and it is able to handle the documents.**  Still takes time (some "not responding"), but so far always come back after a few minutes for large find and replace or applying styles.  I removed the create indexes fields at the end of the document as soon as I converted from rtf to docx, then added them back after I did most of the editing, then freeze the fields while working on the rest of the document.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).